# Error Could not locate the binding file. JS/TS on VS code

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, npm, npm-install

When I run `npm start`, this happens and nothing works, not `npm install binding` not `npm repair` doesn't help, at this point, I'm hopeless and hope for community help <3 I'm new to Stack overflow so I can post only links :(

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I did `npm install deasync` and afterward `npm install` and it worked.